# Open new buffer frame instead of switching the current

Tags: emacs, coffeescript

I'm currently using [Emacs coffee-mode](https://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode).

When I call the `coffee-compile-region` method (see [the source here](https://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode/blob/master/coffee-mode.el#L279-294)), the compiled buffer is shown on the current buffer.

I'd like to see it in a new frame (just like the *standard* `*Compilation*` buffer work), instead of hiding the current.

I guess the problems come from this line:

```
(switch-to-buffer (get-buffer coffee-compiled-buffer-name))
```

But I'd like to do it without editing the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was truly a personal thing then, then you can do what you want by using defadvice and flet.  But in this case what you want should be the default.  So instead, you should fork it make the change and submit a pull-request with explanation.

`switch-to-buffer` should be `pop-to-buffer`.

Comment: It does not fit exactly what I want, but I guess there is no better solution...Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "not fit exactly"?

Comment: I'd like to not edit the source code. But anyway, I've made a pull request (http://goo.gl/uWgN0) that is now merged. So its not a problem for me now!